# Ruby Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user root@xxxxxxxxx

Tags: ruby, ssh

I am trying to SSH into another server via the Rails console, however, get the below error. I tried pretty much every suggestion that I could find online but still get the same error. I can login to the server with SSH no problem `ssh root@xxx.x.xxx.x`.

```
    Net::SSH.start("xxx.xx.xx.x","root",:keys=> ["ssh-rsa ........"], :verbose => Logger::DEBUG) do |ssh| 
       puts ssh
    end


D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.604405 #30930] DEBUG -- socket[3fcf45daf8a0]: queueing packet nr 3 type 5 len 28
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.604540 #30930] DEBUG -- socket[3fcf45daf8a0]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.643325 #30930] DEBUG -- socket[3fcf45daf8a0]: read 52 bytes
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.643674 #30930] DEBUG -- socket[3fcf45daf8a0]: received packet nr 3 type 6 len 28
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.643897 #30930] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fcf4c354a20]: trying none
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.644151 #30930] DEBUG -- socket[3fcf45daf8a0]: queueing packet nr 4 type 50 len 44
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.644285 #30930] DEBUG -- socket[3fcf45daf8a0]: sent 68 bytes
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.646320 #30930] DEBUG -- socket[3fcf45daf8a0]: read 52 bytes
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.646501 #30930] DEBUG -- socket[3fcf45daf8a0]: received packet nr 4 type 51 len 28
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.646664 #30930] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fcf4c354a20]: allowed methods: publickey
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.646807 #30930] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.none[3fcf4c341718]: none failed
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.646918 #30930] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fcf4c354a20]: trying publickey
D, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.647084 #30930] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fcf4c32ebf4]: connecting to ssh-agent
E, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.647262 #30930] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fcf4c32ebf4]: could not connect to ssh-agent: Permission denied - connect(2) for /tmp/ssh-LmmHflAUE4b4/agent.28067
E, [2018-08-31T09:25:57.647375 #30930] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fcf4c354a20]: all authorization methods failed (tried none, publickey)
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user root@xxx.xx.xx.x
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/net-ssh-5.0.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:259:in `start'
    from (irb):2
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:14:in `require'
    from bin/rails:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `keys=> ["ssh-rsa ........"]` Looks like you have the contents of the .pub file in there. That's the public portion of the key. You need to supply the private portion of the key, which is in the other file.

Comment: @kenster thank you for your reply, but I tried with private as well, also converting private to .pem format still same error :(

Comment: Can you SSH just fine from terminal?

Comment: @Max yeah, works fine with `ssh root@ip....`. Also script works fine from my local mac machine, so its something not configured with that box.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so its nothing to do with the library/keys or `SSH` itself, I am trying to do this from `gitlab-rails c`, it works fine from `irb` on the same server.